# Is there a way to display elements from an ngFor only once when displaying a 2D string array?

Tags: html, angular

I have a 2D nested string array that I am trying to display the contents of each inner array as a table. I want the first table to display the first array index values and the second table to display the second index values.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let h of headers; let h = index">
   <ng-container *ngFor = "let rows of test; let i = index">
      <ng-container *ngFor = "let row of rows; let j = index">
         <label *ngIf="h===i">
            {{row}}
         </label>
      </ng-container>
   </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

When I tried doing something like this in the ngIf it displays like this

Header1

| Table1 |
| --- |
| Test1 |
| Test2 |
| Test1 |
| Test2 |

Header2

| Table2 |
| --- |
| Test3 |
| Test4 |
| Test5 |
| Test3 |
| Test4 |
| Test5 |

when I want it to display like this:

| Table1 |
| --- |
| Test1 |
| Test2 |

| Table2 |
| --- |
| Test3 |
| Test4 |
| Test5 |

In the .ts file I have headers and my 2D string array

```
headers = ['Header1', 'Header2']
test = [['Test1', 'Test2'], ['Test3', 'Test4', 'Test5']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here you can try this logic :**

**component.ts**

```
public headers = ['Header1', 'Header2'];
  public test = [
    ['Test1', 'Test2'],
    ['Test3', 'Test4', 'Test5'],
  ];
```

**component.html**

```js
<ng-container *ngFor="let a of headers; let i = index">
  <h2>{{ a }}</h2>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let b of test[i]; let j = index">
    <h2>{{ b }}</h2>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: When I added *ngFor="let b of test[i]", I got an error that says cannot find a differ supporting object 'test4' of type string. NGFor only supports binding to ITerables such as Arrays

Comment: working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-nhkspn?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts